# Selecting a value from a drop-down menu with curl

Tags: bash, curl

I'm trying to fetch this page on Linux, in a bash script: `https://www.worldcoinindex.com/coin/siacoin`

When it's firstly explored on browser, it shows off Siacoin's prices in USD. On the page there's a drop-down menu that you can use to select in which currency you'd like to see the current currency prices. I'd like to fetch Siacoin's prices in BTC. After a few research I was able to find the form id, `tn_q` and ended up with the following command:

```
curl --silent -d tn_q="BTC" --connect-timeout 2 https://www.worldcoinindex.com/coin/siacoin |html2text|grep siacoin|grep SC|head -n1| awk '{ print $4 }'
```

But it fails to show what I'm looking for, it still shows price in USD.

I'm lost, as the URL of the site won't change when you set the expected value from the drop-down, and I don't know how to tell curl to set this field for me.

**Edit #1**:

I tried the cookie way, with no success. Found the following cookie on my Chrome, but still getting USD price.

```
curl --silent --cookie "WCI-CURRENCY=btc" --connect-timeout 2 https://www.worldcoinindex.com/coin/siacoin |html2text|grep siacoin|grep SC|head -n1| awk '{ print $4 }'
```

Comment: I've worked around this using other sites APIs for getting the coins prices in JSON and then parsing with jq -r in order to get them working as variables in my bash script.

Comment: I don't know why, but your "edit" version with cookie works fine for me. Maybe because i previously used `lynx https://www.worldcoinindex.com/coin/siacoin` to access the web page and i accepted manually all the cookies; this is a lynx procedure that is not automatically storing all the cookies but user confirmation is required.

Comment: After your comment I tried with wget --save-cookies and then wget --load-cookies after editing the cookie file and it worked!

Comment: Great! By the way i noticed that this particular cookie expires in 24 hours.... Maybe this can be changed (if editable) in 24 years :)

Comment: Of course I was checking for testing purposes, each of the sites where Worldcoinindex takes prices from support public APIs, so the best way to take coin prices from to use as variables in the script is by far from each site's JSON, parsed with "jq -r" and I'm already developing the script with this new approach.

Comment: We have edit history, no need to pollute your post with **EDIT** stuff, just rewrite the post to be a single coherent whole including the information added at a later date.

Comment: @Anthon I've circumvented the problem represented here. What should I do with this question then? Did I get your downvote because of the Edit stuff or there's something else?

Comment: Although individual actions steps you take can be interesting, just tagging them onto a question as you experienced them is not necessarily the best way to present the question. For latecomers to your post that is just not relevant. This is [se] there is no need to comment to downvote or vv., so there is no way to tell why you got downvoted.

Comment: I think explanations of downvotes are very important for who takes care of the site's quality and not just to fix his own problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A decent web browser debugger will allow you to discover that the currency is set as a cookie.

```
curl --silent --cookie WCI-CURRENCY=btc --connect-timeout 2 https://www.worldcoinindex.com/coin/siacoin |
    tee siacoin.html |
    html2text |
    tee siacoin.txt |
    grep SC

[Siacoin] siacoin SC    0.00000169 %      0.00000178  0.00000161 1,429  14,050,000,000 23,745
****** siacoin SC ******
****** siacoin SC ******
Poloniex      SC/BTC 0.00000170  700
Bittrex       SC/BTC 0.00000169  466
Yunbi         SC/CNY 0.00000164  264
Total/Average SC/BTC 0.00000169  1,429
```